# Adding an attachment to an email form: Integrating PHPmailer for handling the attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

Below is my PHP script that handles the input from an HTML form. The script works great, but after trying and trying, I couldn't get plain old PHP code to handle an attachment from the form.

After reading for days and testing different code, everyone suggests using a pre-made application to simplify the attachment. (I chose PHPmailer.)

I've tried to get it working, but all I can find are examples of static files:

**Example from the PHPmailer readme:**

> $mail->AddAttachment("c:\temp\js-bak.sql");  // add attachments
>
> $mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

My question is, it possible to attach a file using a "file" selector from the HTML form?
If so, can I integrate the PHPmailer attachment code into my production script without having to recode the entire file?

What code do I need to attach the file from my form?

**My current script:**

```
<?php

require("phpmailer.inc.php");
$email = new phpmailer;
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $email->AddAttachment($uploadfile);
} else {
    echo "File failed to attach. Maximum size of 5mb\n";    
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "example@abc.com";
    $email_subject = "IT Request (Support)";  //Email Subject


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation: expected data already exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['datereg']) || 
    !isset($_POST['message']) || 
    !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];                 //Required
    $request_date = $_POST['datereg'];      //Required
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];       //Required
    $message = $_POST['message'];           //Not required
    $error_message = "";    
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_address)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[\$A-Za-z0-9._%-]/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$request_date)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Request Date you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    } 
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$message)) {
        $error_message .= 'You must list a description in order to submit the form.<br />';
    }     
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "---IT Request Form Content---\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    //These fields are required per validation so they don't need to be tested.
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date of Request: ".clean_string($request_date)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Description: ".clean_string($message)."\n";  

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_address."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_address."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

    <!-- include your own success html here -->

    Thank you for submitting an IT Support Request. Your information will be reviewed as soon as possible.
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2;URL=http://getsupport/index.html">

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Once the file is uploaded, it's a regular file on the disk. So you just have to attach it like any other file.

Comment: don't forget to do the usual: check if uploaded, file type is correct, not too large, archive off/delete once attached etc..

Comment: $email->AddAttachment($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']); where $email is an instance of your PHPmailer class.

Comment: Ok I updated my original script.
I'm now getting the file tested for size and uploaded to the server.

The form sends like normal but the file is not being attached.
What code am I missing to include the attachment?

Am I required to recode all of my email compilation bits at the bottom to include $email->AddAttachment($uploadfile); ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the path to the temporary file and the name of the file in the `$_FILES` variable. Take a look at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I was skipping the size\type validation.
After its working, I would add it back in. Is it a requirement for the attach to function?